# Can't cast gson to my Object type

Tags: java, android, gson

I've looked at other questions with the same error but they all seem specific to that user's situation. I was unable to find a solution to my problem.

I'm using gson in my Android app to save a list of my custom object into sharedPreferences. The object is very basic:

```
public class Idea {
    private String title;
    private String details;

    public Idea (String title, String details) {
        this.title = title;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public void setTitle(String newTitle) { title = newTitle; }

    public String getDetails() { return details; }

    public void setDetails(String newDetails) { details = newDetails; }
}
```

The list is declared like this:

```
private static List<Idea> ideas = new ArrayList<Idea>();
```

Serialization seems to work OK but when I try to decode it in the MainActivity like so:

```
String jsonIdeas = sharedPref.getString(IDEAS_KEY, null);
Gson gson = new Gson();
ideas = gson.fromJson(jsonIdeas, ArrayList.class);
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr/com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.Idea
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.Idea
            at com.zarwanhashem.ideatrackr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I don't think the location I'm getting in the stack trace is accurate because it changes whenever I debug the app. But by break pointing and evaluating in IntelliJ I was able to narrow the error down to decoding code I posted above.

Just in case the serialization is actually not OK, here's the code I'm using:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ideas);
editor.putString(IDEAS_KEY, json); //putting it into sharedPreferences
```

The gson was working fine when I was using it to store a list of string lists, but when I carried over the code to use with my custom object I started getting this error.

Comment: first google result is an answer ...

Comment: Link me? I tried searching but didn't find a solution for my problem. I also wonder if you read the first line in my question. @Selvin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a gson [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r899/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html).  TypeTokens are needed when you are trying to deserialize generic types.

For your case, it would be something like --

```
Type typeOfListOfIdea = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Idea>>(){}.getType();
ideas = gson.fromJson(jsonIdeas, typeOfListOfIdea);
```

Your other option is to convert it as an array instead of an `ArrayList`.

```
Idea ideas[] = gson.fromJson(jsonIdeas, Idea[].class);
```

Then you can load into an `ArrayList` (or convert with the [`Arrays.asList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method.

Comment: How is my Idea class a generic type? I though generic types are when you use <T>

Comment: Your class isn't, but ArrayList is.

Comment: It worked fine before when I was dealing with List<List<String>> though, is that because I was using string?

Comment: Yes, a `String` is like a primitive datatype to GSON, it knows how to deal with Strings.

Comment: FYI, added an alternate method that works for arrays if you don't want to deal with `TypeToken`s

Comment: It worked, thanks. One thing to note though is that with the TypeToken solution I was getting null when the list was empty instead of an empty list, so I had to add a check.